# replace all the columns from import csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas

How to replace all the series of column value separated by `;` in the CSV file?

```
column A column B
       1       3;5
       4       3;7;11;14
       7       5;7;13;14
```

How to replace the column `B` by `3`=`HQ3`, `5`=`HQT5`,`7`=`HTS7`,`11`=`HS11`, `13`=`BST13` and `14`=`HFS14`?

Answer (score 1):

You can split the column with `.str.split` + `explode`, replace the values with `replace`, and join it back together with `groupby(level=0)` + `agg(list)` + `.str.join`:

```
d = {
    '3': 'HQ3',
    '5': 'HQT5',
    '7': 'HTS7',
    '11': 'HS11',
    '13': 'BST13',
    '14': 'HFS14'
}

df['columnB'] = df['columnB'].str.split(';').explode().replace(d).groupby(level=0).agg(list).str.join(';')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   columnA                columnB
0        1               HQ3;HQT5
1        4    HQ3;HTS7;HS11;HFS14
2        7  HQT5;HTS7;BST13;HFS14
```